# Asp.Net Windows Authentication for new Domain USers

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, windows-authentication

We have an Asp.net webapplication in production running all these years. Now, the company is creating a new Domain and want the users from the new domain to have access to the Asp.Net web application. The server in which our application is hosted is still in the old domain and it is not going to be changed. The Infra team has given us new AD server name where the new domain resides and asking us to make our application to allow users from the new domain. As far as i know, we don't specify the AD server to authenticate in Web.Config except setting Authentication mode to Windows.

What we need is, we need to allow users from the existing domain and users from the new domain to have access to the application. Please let me know how to do this..Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Bala

Answer (score 1):

You need a Kerberos cross-realm trust. One way should suffice.

Comment: Within the context of two AD domains, it'd be a domain or forest trust. You're correct it only needs to be one-way (where the domain hosting the web server trusts the foreign user domain).